# Edujugon push notification Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, push-notification, laravel-9

`composer require edujugon/push-notification` is not installable in laravel 9.

my composer.json is as below

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0.0",
        "arcanedev/log-viewer": "^9.0",
        "brian2694/laravel-toastr": "^5.56",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "kyslik/column-sortable": "^6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.2",
        "laravel/passport": "*",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.4",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.0",
        "league/glide-laravel": "^1.0",
        "twilio/sdk": "^6.36",
        "vinkla/hashids": "^10.0"
    },
```

Error is below:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires edujugon/push-notification ^5.0 -> satisfiable by edujugon/push-notification[v5.0.0].
    - edujugon/push-notification v5.0.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.8 || ^6.0 || ^7.0 || ^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require edujugon/push-notification:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require edujugon/push-notification:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Answer (score 0):

`
public function update(Request $request)
{

```
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name'=>"required",
        'title'=>"required",
        'job'=>'required',
        'blogs'=>'required',
        ]);

        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->name               =$request->name;
        $user->profile->title      =$request->title;
        $user->profile->job        =$request->job;
        $user->profile->blogs       =$request->blogs;
        $user->save();
        $user->profile->save();
        return redirect()->back();
}
```

}`

Comment: You need to update proper informations. Please do refer, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer before writing answers